# How can I skip greylisting for servers with a valid SPF Record in Postgrey?

Tags: postfix, spf, greylisting

I typically do not use grey listing as it doesn't play nice with multiple mx servers, but I do like preventing direct-access attempts to email me (use an MTA, or don't send email).

**I would like to prevent grey-listing for any server that has a valid SPF record.**

**How can I combine (2) check_policy_services?**

Server Setup:
Centos7, Postfix, PostGrey, OpenDKIM, SPF, RBLs (listed), as well as TLS support.

`postconf | grep smtpd_recipient_restrictions
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname, reject_invalid_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname, reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_invalid_hostname,check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_access, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client b.barracudacentral.org, reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net, check_policy_service unix:private/policy, check_policy_service unix:postgrey/socket, permit`

Comment: One way i can think of is to use a single policy service that does the decision if the mail should be accepted

Comment: Then how can I combine check_policy_service to do SPF, then grey-list.

Comment: good point to start is to look into perl-spf-policy (that makes SPF verification). You could (based on the result of this) either return direct or exec an external piece of code (like graylisting)